# Why is "where T : class" required in this example?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, filehelpers

Sample code :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using FileHelpers;

....
private void Save<T>(string destFilename,  IEnumerable<T> data) where T : class    
{
    var engine = new FileHelperEngine((typeof(T)));


    engine.HeaderText = engine.GetFileHeader(); 
    engine.WriteFile(destFilename, data); // XX
}
```

At line XX, the 2nd parameter to engine.WriteFile is expecting an IEnumerable<object>. This code works ok.

My question is, why is the "where T : class" constraint required on the method ? If I remove it, I get the compile time error :

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' to
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>'
```

I would have thought that everything was an "object", and so that the constraint was not necessary ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constraint is needed because `object` is a reference type only; the reason value types can be assigned to `object` is due to boxing (even though, technically, all types inherit from `System.Object`).

But boxing is a separate issue from type parameter variance; an `IEnumerable<T>` with an unconstrained T cannot be converted to an `IEnumerable<object>` because variance is not supported for value types.

As an aside, `FileHelperEngine<T>`, which the non-generic `FileHelperEngine` inherits from (as `FileHelperEngine<object>`), also has a `T : class` constraint. So you're not missing any functionality by having the constraint since only reference types are supported anyway — one could theoretically just use `FileHelperEngine<T>` directly without going through the non-generic class, since the method given in the sample is already generic:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using FileHelpers;

....
private void Save<T>(string destFilename,  IEnumerable<T> data) where T : class    
{
    var engine = new FileHelperEngine<T>();


    engine.HeaderText = engine.GetFileHeader(); 
    engine.WriteFile(destFilename, data);
}
```

Comment: thanks. Also that last paragraph about FileHelpers is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to apply `T` to `FileHelperEngine<T>` which already has the same constraint, `T : class`. The compiler can tell that if you don't put that same constraint on your method then `T` could be invalid for `FileHelperEngine<T>`.
So it's just preventing type mismatches.

Comment: that's true if one is using FileHelperEngine<T>, as in BoltClock's sample. But it doesn't seem to be the case when using FIleHelperEngine(Type recordType) as in my original example.